# Mixed programming between scheme and C

Tags: c, scheme, ffi, chez-scheme, mixed-programming

I'm reading the CSUG to learn the FFI of chez-scheme. So I may have some beginner's error.
I just want to know is there some question of FFI.
C have some type of data, just like char, float, double, int, functions, struct, union, or enumeration.
But they are not existed in scheme.
There is number, list, character, string and symbol. Or the `defstruct` macro

Is there some not compatible between their data type.
If it's exit, What's the solution of the FFI.

Comment: Chapter 4 of the User's Guide, "Foreign Interface", discusses the topic pretty well. For additional detail, I read the Chez Scheme source. In particular, I found the source for the expediter (REPL) in expeditor.c very informative.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.